# Published Page versus Preview of same page

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, page-layout, site-logo

I have a SharePoint Online classic site in which my designated site logo does not appear when normally browsing (there is just a blank space where it should be).  However, the logo *does* appear in the various site settings pages, and also when I edit the page and view that same page's 'Preview' mode.

The site, which I've inherited, does have custom page layouts and CSS and I believe that's where my issue is though I'm struggling to narrow it down, given that everything looks OK on those settings/preview pages.

Is there a particular site setting or Master Page/CSS/ASPX-file that I should be looking at?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your custom css is hiding the logo. Try to inspect the logo element using browsers developer tool and see css for classes assigned to logo.

Comment: Thanks, I found it using your instructions - it was hidden using "display:none".

Comment: welcome. please accept and upvote an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your custom css is hiding the site logo.

Try to inspect the logo element using browsers developer tool and see custom css for classes assigned to logo.

Use below link to Inspect the styles:

[Inspect and Edit Pages and Styles](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/).